# Unexpected error AEE_EBADCLASS when calling ISHELL_BrowseURL

Tags: c, brew-framework, brewmp

[ISHELL_BrowseURL](https://developer.brewmp.com/reference/api/brew-mp-102/ishellbrowseurl) returns AEE_EBADCLASS when callled with a URL. (Such as http://google.com/)

The "po" (IShell*) argument is as far as we know OK. Do you have any advice regarding this? Close applet with the same class works, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [HTC Smart](https://developer.brewmp.com/device/htc-f3188-smart) (Same as [HTC F3188](https://developer.brewmp.com/device/htc-f3188-smart) or Dopod F3188), the standard browser can not be called.

Instead, call the HTC browser with id 0x0108d987:

> int ret = ISHELL_StartAppletArgs(pMe->applet.m_pIShell, 0x0108d987,
>   "http://developer.att.com");